# SQL Procedure error for position in ranking

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I'm pretty new at SQL Proceures, so sorry for eventual stupid questions.

I'm trying to create an SQL procedure to return the position of a team in a ranking, comparing its points with the points of all the other teams.
The code is the following, but I always get SQl error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getTeamPosition`( @sqd INT(11), @gio INT(11), @camp INT(11) ) AS           
       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT points)+1 as position
            FROM ranking
            WHERE chaday = @gio AND champ = @camp AND points > (
                SELECT points 
                FROM ranking
                WHERE chaday = @gio AND champ = @camp AND team = @sqd)
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you want a procedure, function, or view?  You have not declared your procedure with any way to return values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think that a procedure should be the best solution, isn't it? If I add "return position;" at the end the problem still exist.

Comment: Whats the SQL error you get?